# Python list.insert() multi-index / list of list

Tags: python, numpy

For performance reasons I'd like to use the Python list insert() method. I will demonstrate why:

My final list is a 31k * 31k matrix:

```
w=31*10**3
h=31*10**3
distance_matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```

I intent to update the matrix one iteration at the time:

```
for i in range(len(index)):
                    for j in range(len(index)):
                        distance_matrix[index[i]][index[j]] = k[0][i][j]
```

Obviously this doesn't perform well.

I'd rather like to start with an empty list and fill it up gradually, making the computation intense at the end of the process (and easy at the beginning):

```
distance_matrix = []
for i in range(len(index)):
                    for j in range(len(index)):
                        distance_matrix.insert([index[i]][index[j]], k[0][i][j])
```

But this multi-index or list-in-list insert doesn't seem to be possible.

How would you advise to proceed? I've also looked into numpy arrays, but without luck so far.

To be precise: updating the (ordered) large array of zeros index by index is the issue here. In a DataFrame I can use custom columns/indices, but that is not scalable in performance.

Additional information:
I split up the entire original data matrix in parts to compute distance matrices in parallel. The issue in this process is to aggregate the distance matrix again with the computed values. The distance matrix/array is very large, therefore a simple list insert or edit takes very long.

Comment: Normally if we build a list, or list of lists, iteratively, we use `list.append`.  For each row start with a `[]`, append values to it, and then append it to the row list.

Comment: What is `k`?  Is it just another list of lists?  You index it like a list  If so, why not a deep copy?

Comment: k is another distance matrix and also a list of lists, but the ordering is key. That's why the list of indices (index) is used to place it at the appropriate position in distance_matrix.

Comment: This matrix is very big. I think, it will take at least 20GB memory with pure python. Are you sure that you have enough memory? If you have enough memory, I don't think numpy can help you here because random access in numpy can be as slow as python list. May I ask you in which context do you use this code? Maybe it can be possible to vectorize some parts with numpy without converting to distance matrix?

Comment: The matrix fits in memory,  it's roughly 10**4 cells. The context is distance matrices of timeseries, a lot of them. I've also thought about making a dictionary with x,y coordinates and values. And then a one time ordering at the end. But I can't grasp if it would perform better

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach achieves what I had in mind:

```
distance_matrix = []
def dynamic_append(x,i,j,val):
    if((len(x)-1)<i):
        dif_x = i-len(x)+1
        for k in range(dif_x):
            x.append([])
        dif_y = j-len(x[i])+1
        for l in range(dif_y):
            x[i].append([])
    elif((len(x[i])-1)<j):
        dif_y = j-len(x[i])+1
        for l in range(dif_y):
            x[i].append([])
    x[i][j]=val
    return(x)

for i in range(len(index)):
                    for j in range(len(index)):
                        distance_matrix=dynamic_append(distance_matrix,index[i],index[j],k[0][i][j])
```